# Two Slit Experiment with polarized filters

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

If I did a two slit experiment with linear polarized filters in the two paths presumably I would see not interference if they were a 90 deg to each other.

If they were aligned presumably the interference would appear.

What happens in between? Could I do a Bell in inequality type measurement with one photon?

Answer (score 1):

In between 0 and 90 degrees angle between the two linear polarizers, you will see reduced contrast fringes.  You can do Bell inequality experiments with polarizers in an interferometer, one photon at a time, but to get meaningful results you need to combine a lot of single-photon detections.

Answer (score 0):

You can always split polarization 2 in two perpendicular directions i.e. parallel to the polarization 1 and perpendicular to the polarization 1. Now the parallel polarization will interfere with each other. You will see fringes of visibility  $\frac{I_1-I_2}{I_1+I_2}$. Where intensities can be calculated by relation $I_2=I_1\cos^2\theta$. Other component i.e. $I_1\sin^2\theta$ will add to constant background. (assuming that initial intensities from both slits are same).

Hope it will answer your query.